# Why is the array is not being deleted instead another array added after setState update?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, sorting

I want to rerender the array whenever myData updates but the old array remains in place and new arrays are being created instead. The component containing myData should rerender whenever the state is being updates but it doesn't.

```
      useEffect(() => {
        if(itemIdToMoveOnTop){
          setIsLoading(true)
          setMyData(null);
    
          let sortedData = [...myData]; // create a copy of myData
    
          // Sort the array
          sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.id === itemIdToMoveOnTop) {
              return -1;
            } else if (b.id === itemIdToMoveOnTop) {
              return 1;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          });
    
          // Filter the array
          sortedData = sortedData.filter((item) => item.info);
    
          setMyData(sortedData); // update myData with the sorted and filtered data
          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      }, [itemIdToMoveOnTop]);
...
     {isLoading ? (
      <div>Loading...</div> // replace with your loading component or spinner
    ) : (myData
        // {myData
          .filter((item) => item.info)
          .map((item) => (
            <div className="bg-teal-500">
              <div className="flex flex-row">
                <Speech
                  ref={speechRef}
                  key={item.id}
```

Comment: Add a language to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Javascript.  array.sort() sorts the items in your array in place (same array).  array.filter() returns a new array consisting of only the items that meet the criteria.

Comment: Ty, after resetting myData the old array remains and new arrays are added every time myData is resetted. Even after all the array.filter() methods removed.

Comment: Probably have to include more of your code to find the answer then.  Looks like you have a function named SetMyData(), my guess would be the problem is in there.   If you're getting new arrays, you're most likely still using a method like array.filter() that will create a new array with the results of the operation.  This leaves the initial array intact and would result in no change to your UI.